# MooTools - implement element method

Tags: mootools

```
var parent = el.getParent();

parent.getElement('div[class=test]'); // return array

var parent1 = el.parentNode;

parent1.getElement('div[class=test]'); // error getElement is not a function
```

It seems parent1 doesn't have all element methods of MooTools, how to extend all element method of parent1, like in [page](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element)

Note: I have to use parentNode.

Answer (score 1):

`parent.getElement('div[class=test]');`

should really be

`parent.getElement("div.test");`

there's a substantial difference going to `element.getParent()` and `element.parentNode` - it boils down to `Element` prototype, which cannot be extended in old versions of IE.

mootools works around that by saving a reference to the methods directly on the elements instead as properties.

hence if you do `element.getParent()` and that returns an `element`, this will extend it to have all the prototypes. `element.parentNode` returns a simple element object, which will work in browsers where the `Element.prototype` is inherited correctly.

you can make the second method work in IE by doing:

```
var parent1 = el.parentNode;
$(parent1).getElement("div.test");
```

Subsequent references to parent1 do not need the `$` (or `document.id`) as the element will already have been extended.

so to summarize the answer:

to make an element extended, you need to run it through a selector.

```
var parent = el.parentNode;
$(parent); // this extends it.

parent.getElements("div.test").something()
```

Answer (score 0):

Both ways work just fine on an element, proof: http://jsfiddle.net/SuJn6/

I assume what you're doing wrong is your `el` is actually an Element Collection, not a single element. In which case you need to loop your first array, and only then use `parentNode`, example: http://jsfiddle.net/35Fxf/

Pro-tip: name your variable carefully, `el` and `els` - all makes a huge difference.

Comment: this is the first time i see you give a wrong answer on a mootools question! :) only way this can work in IE 6-8 is if you did `var child = $(parent).getElement('div[id="b"]');`

Comment: *scratching my head*. Can it really be that all of my code doesn't work on IE 6-8? ;-)

Comment: haha. depends. you can be lucky. if you favour `element.inject(document.body)` instead of `document.body.adopt(element)` (for instance) - no worries. or if a selector has passed the element or you created it. that's why people sometimes do `$(document.body)` in classes

Comment: Ah, I see. I was sure `document.body` was one of those off-cases where it wasn't extended for performance reasons. Actually wasn't aware there was more cases like this. Thanks for the clarification Dimitar! :-)